# way to delete cookie

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have a questione about how to delete a cookie from a servlet. Let's presume that client has already a cookie sent by my servlet, one solution to delete it is to set the max age of cookie to 0. But what's the difference to set it like:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[i].getName().equals("cookie_name")) {
            cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

or sent a new cookie and overwrite the old one like

```
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("cookie_name", "");
response.addCookie(myCookie);
```

? and the cookie will be deleted immediatly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first way checks if the cookie exists in client and then delete it, and that the second way outright deletes the cookie without checking if it exists in client. Makes logically sense, right? Ultimately, they have both the same effect: telling the browser to remove the cookie associated with the given name (and path).

You seem to be somehow assuming that the `Cookie` instance returned by `getCookies()` represents the **actual** cookie as the browser itself is using and that you have to use *exactly* that cookie instance in order to be able to delete it. This assumption is utterly wrong. It's just an abstraction of the cookie sent by the browser in the request headers. You can perfectly create a new `Cookie` instance, as long as it's using exactly the same name and path.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIAK,There is no evidence that the  method  `addCookie`  won't check for the duplicates cookies.

It is up to you that to delete your [cookie](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt),before setting a new one, other wise you application  the behavior is **undefined**.

It's better to delete.